# js-xlsx: How to delete row with merged cells?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, js-xlsx

I'm trying to get json data out of xlsx file but stumbled upon weird 'js-xlsx' behaviour. If I have a table with merged cells in the heading then I get only first row of data in output from the table. If i delete this row manually (in EXCEL) - then I get all data as it should be. If I unmerge this cell manually - once again: all data in json.

So the problem is with the merged cells and the task is to skip it\avoid it in export\delete it\do smth whatever else...

I tried to delete this row via 'js-xlsx', got some code from SO accepted answer but it's not helping and seems a bit odd dealing with merged cells:

```
    const XLSX = require('xlsx');
    let workbook = XLSX.readFile('./downloads/wb_sales.xlsx');
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

    function ec(r, c){
        return XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r:r,c:c});
    }
    function delete_row(ws, row_index){
        var variable = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"])
        for(var R = row_index; R < variable.e.r; ++R){
            for(var C = variable.s.c; C <= variable.e.c; ++C){
                ws[ec(R,C)] = ws[ec(R+1,C)];
            }
        }
        variable.e.r--
        ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(variable.s, variable.e);
    }
    // trying to delete first row
    delete_row(worksheet,0)

    // here I get just the first row of data
    console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));
```

Tried `worksheet[!'merged']=''` - it clears the cell, but merged status stays.

Tried

```
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
        range.s.r = 1; // <-- skipping first row with merged cell, but not working either.
        worksheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
```

No good. Same output.

Tried `worksheet['A1']=worksheet['A2']` it copies content but merging stays.

Regarding above said:

1. How to delete first row in this task (not clearing cells content but deleting)?
2. How do I unmerge merged cells?
3. How do I delete merged cells (not clearing the cell, but deleting it).

Rays of gratefulness to all :)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to exclude the row with merged cell using range encoding. It's kind of when you manually select cells with mouse. Unfortunately it is half-solution because it does not solve problems with merged cells in random places in table and they still stay merged causing problems. Anyway here's simple ranges solution if anyone would look for it.

```
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']); //<-- start "select"
    range.s.r = 1; // <-- start row
    range.e.r = 12; // <-- end row
    worksheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range); //<-- end "select"
```

UPD: Ok, so I managed it through some bizzare technique. 1. Take the range 2. Export to json 3. Create new workbook 4. Export json to sheet 5. Append sheet to workbook 6. Save as new xlsx object.

So this is next block:

```
    let ws_json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet)

    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    var ws = wb.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

    let js = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(ws_json)
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, js, '');

    XLSX.writeFile(wb,'./downloads/wb_sales_new.xlsx')
```

If somebody finds direct solution please update.